# Batch renaming files on Windows Command Line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window, rename, command-prompt

I have several files generated by a build script that look like this:

```
sfml-audio-s-d.lib
sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
sfml-system-s-d.lib
...
```

I need to rename them to remove the `-s-d` part (which in certain cases can be just `-s`). After searching around SO for an hour I thought it would be simple to do using the rename command:

```
Ren ".\sfml-*-*.lib" "sfml-*.lib"
```

Hoverever it isn't changing any of the files in the directory.

What is the correct (and ideally one-liner) approach to renaming these files?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few issue's you're having with your command. Firstly, it looks like you're attempting to rename a file with only `-s`. The problem is that `Ren "sfml-*-*.lib" ""` cannot assume the wildcard from the file path. Meaning that the `REN` does not know what to put for the `*` in `"sfml-*.lib"`.

To get around this, you will need to address what the `*` is. To do this, a `FOR` statement can be used. The first thing the FOR statement will need is the filenames. Using the command `For /f %%A In ('dir /b *.lib') Do (Echo %%A)` will list all the file names. The issue now is that we only want `audio` in `sfml-audio-s.lib`.

To grab only certain objects using a `FOR` statement, you can add `/f "tokens=2" %%A`. This will tell the statement to only grab the second word in phrase. The problem in this scenario is that this only works if `sfml-audio-s.lib` was spaced `sfml audio s.lib`. By adding `delims=-` the statement will ignore all `-` in the parse. More info on that [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

**From CMD:** *(Be sure to CD to directory location)*

Remove "-s" from *.lib file names

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %A In ('dir /b *.lib') Do (Ren "sfml-*-*.lib" "sfml-%A.lib" 2>NUL)
```

Remove "-s-d" from *.lib file names

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %A In ('dir /b *.lib') Do (Ren "sfml-*-*-*.lib" "sfml-%A.lib" 2>NUL)
```

**From BATCH:** *(Add `CD C:\folder location` to the script)*

Remove "-s" from *.lib file names

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%A In ('dir /b *.lib') Do (Ren "sfml-*-*.lib" "sfml-%%A.lib" 2>NUL)
```

Remove "-s-d" from *.lib file names

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%A In ('dir /b *.lib') Do (Ren "sfml-*-*-*.lib" "sfml-%%A.lib" 2>NUL)
```